# Loop based in variable value in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

I have to output a table based on value of a variable. I have a unique block of table with variables. Depending on the view there should be a loop the re-read the table.

The variable could have the values **Two** or **Three** or both. I have to output the table with view **One** in all the cases.

**Example #1:**

```
Views = "Two, Three"
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View Two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Example #2:**

```
Views = "Two"
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View Two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Example #3:**

```
Views = "Three"
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tried to mix some While and For, without success.

```
<%
i=2
Do While i = 0
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><% Response.Write i %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%
   i=i-1
Loop
%>
```

Comment: Please show actual code of what you have now, makes it easier to understand what "unique block of table" means.

Comment: What happened to "Two" and "Three" ? Or will it be "2" and "3" ? And in your edit, i is the View ? I am sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: The code is just a try. `i=2` will be `Views = "Two, Three"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
<%
Dim Views : Views ="Two"    'Change this to check

Response.write "Initial View =" & Views & "<br/>"

'But "One" will always be printed
If InStr(Views,"One")=0 Then
    'add if there is no "One" already
    Views = Views & ",One"
End If


Response.write "New View =" & Views & "<br/>"

Dim ArrValues : ArrValues =Array("One","Two","Three")

Dim Counter 

For Counter=0 to UBound(ArrValues)
    If InStr(Views,ArrValues(Counter))<>0 Then
    %>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table For View <%=ArrValues(Counter)%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <%
        'Response.write ArrValues(Counter) & "<br/>"
    End If
Next



%>
```

Comment: Looks like we are all misinterpreting the OPs requirement, but honestly that is because the OP hasn't described in enough detail what they want, what they expect and what they have tried. Question should have been closed / put on hold.

Comment: And now i will wait; for the verdict :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Sorry for being not so clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys Did you check my [Updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26842020/692942)? How is this answer any different, sorry but you've been duped.

Comment: I am not tricking anything. I just test the @SearchAndResQ and it works. I tried yours and could not get it to work. But I really appreciate the time you use to help me. Approving an answer doen't mean another is wrong, but the one I approved was more convenient, straight to the point and works.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ You tell me what is different to my approach apart from the fact your answer is less scalable ofc? It's shoddy answers like this that annoy me, we are trying to keep a level of quality while you just want to quick rep hit!

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this would work fine. I just use if else if. Also I compansated for the case that Views could equal "Two, Three" or "Three, Two".

```
<%if Views = "Two" then%>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View One</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View Two</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<%else if Views = "Three"%>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Table For View One</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View Three</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<%else if Views = "Two, Three"%>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View One</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View Two</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View Three</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<%else if Views = "Three, Two"%>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View One</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View Three</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Table For View Two</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<%end if%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply But the table block is actually a unique block of information. Based on views I will loop and output the current values. Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear in the post.

Comment: Not your fault @CodyEsmay the OP hasn't described clearly what they are expecting, I've made the same assumption with my answer. The "unique block" the OP talked about I assumed just meant the OP didn't want the tables duplicating hence my answer.

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple ways to approach this but without changing your code to much, it can be done by splitting your `Views` variable into an Array using the comma `,` as a delimiter. Once you have the Array use a `For` loop to iterate through the Views and use a `Select` statement to return the correct view.

As you specified that Table One will always be included it has been left outside of the loop.

Something like this (not tested);

```vb
<%
Dim item, items
'Build the array from the Views comma separated string
Views = Split(Views, ",")

'Always include Table One
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View One</td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
'Check we have an Array built from the Split().
If IsArray(Views) Then
  'How many views have we requested?
  items = UBound(Views)
  For item = 0 To items
    'What view are we current looking at in the loop?
    Select Case LCase(Trim(Views(item) & ""))
    Case "two"
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View Two</td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
    Case "three"
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
    End Select
  Next
End If
%>
```

Depending on the complexity of your views you could break each table into it's own Sub procedure or one Sub procedure and call in place of the in-line table definitions. Something like below;

```vb
Sub ShowTable(view)
  'Keep all in-line table definitions together.
  Select Case Trim(LCase(view & ""))
  Case "one"
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View One</td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
  Case "two"
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View Two</td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
  Case "three"
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
  End Select
End Sub
```

In the main loop you would added `ShowTable()` calls in place of any in-line table code, for example;

```vb
<%
Dim item, items
'Build the array from the Views comma separated string
Views = Split(Views, ",")

'Always include Table One
Call ShowTable("one")
'Check we have an Array built from the Split().
If IsArray(Views) Then
  'How many views have we requested?
  items = UBound(Views)
  For item = 0 To items
    'What view are we current looking at in the loop?
    Call ShowTable(views(item))
  Next
End If
%>
```

Your output will then look something like this (*if you pass `"Two, Three"`*) for example;

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View One</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View Two</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Table For View Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

> **Update based on OP feedback**
>
> If [you don't want multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819941/loop-based-in-variable-value-in-asp-classic#comment42249645_26842020) (*which is not clear from your question*) then just remove the `<table>` and `</table>` in-line definitions (*in the `ShowTable()` procedure*), this will create the "guts" of your table (*a series of table rows*).
>   Then in the example code above just add `<table>` at the start and after the code `</table>`, which will encapsulate your dynamically generated table rows into one table.
>
> ```vb
> <table>
> <%
> Dim item, items
> 'Build the array from the Views comma separated string
> Views = Split(Views, ",")
>
> 'Always include Table One
> Call ShowTable("one")
> 'Check we have an Array built from the Split().
> If IsArray(Views) Then
>   'How many views have we requested?
>   items = UBound(Views)
>   For item = 0 To items
>     'What view are we current looking at in the loop?
>     Call ShowTable(views(item))
>   Next
> End If
> %>
> </table>
> ```
>
> Your output will then look something like this (*if you pass `"Two, Three"`*) for example;
>
> ```html
> <table>
> <tr>
>   <td>Table For View One</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>Table For View Two</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>Table For View Three</td>
> </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Lankymart. But I have only one block of "table" the view One, Two and Three will use this same block to show data. I have some variables in the table so it will show different info if One, Two or Three.

Comment: @Khrys That isn't what your question shows though is it?? You show what output you are trying to get, by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26819941/edit) your question and I'll modify my answer.

Comment: That was an example of the output. The code i was hoping is in the end of the question.

Comment: @Khrys That code I assumed was your attempt at something and then wrote my code based on the outputs you show in the question. If that isn't what you want, show the outputs you are expecting.

Comment: @Khrys If you just want it all in one table (which isn't clear from your question) remove the `<table>` and `</table>` from the code and then add them before and after, the method is still sound.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Lankymart. I will be more specific next time.

Comment: @Khrys Did you check my updated answer before accepting?

Comment: @Khrys Honestly someone is being petty down-voting my answer! You look at my answer and tell me which of those two outputs you are expecting, I would like to know because so far you've accepted an answer that does the same thing as my answer but requires a lot more manual changing of variables to work, this approach requires you just pass the `Views` variable containing your `"Two"` or `"Two, Three"` string etc. This approach is far more scalable then the hap-hazard answer you accepted!